# GCMNetorkManager PeriodicTask works with 1 minute period, but don't with 2

Tags: android, gcm-network-manager

I've implemented GCMNetworkManager PeriodicTask

I've double-checked all steps according to manual, have read all documentation for GCMNetMan

Setting period with one minute - works perfectly. Setting 2 or 5 minutes - nothing works.

Code in Kotlin:

```
class ScheduleService: GcmTaskService() {
    private val TAG = "ScheduleService"

    override fun onInitializeTasks() {
        Log.wtf(TAG, "onInitializeTasks")
        val gcmMan = GcmNetworkManager.getInstance(this)
        gcmMan.schedule(PeriodicTask.Builder()
            .setPeriod(120000L)
            .setFlex(60000L)
            .setPersisted(true)
            .setService(ScheduleService::class.java)
            .setTag(GPSControl.SCHEDULED)
            .setUpdateCurrent(true)
        .build())
    }

    override fun onRunTask(taskParams: TaskParams): Int {
        Log.wtf(TAG, "onRunTask: ${taskParams.tag}")
        GPSControl.trigger(applicationContext, taskParams.tag)
        if (taskParams.tag == GPSControl.SCHEDULED)
            return GcmNetworkManager.RESULT_RESCHEDULE
        else return GcmNetworkManager.RESULT_SUCCESS
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot. `setPeriod()` and `setFlex()` accepts argument in SECONDS